# check permissions in journal article for specific user

Tags: jakarta-ee, permissions, liferay, liferay-6

I have a class in java with some information, like userId, companyId and JournalArticle. So I need check if this user have permission for view the journalArticle. I saw another post with the same idea but it's not what I need. Which is the best way for do this?

Thank you!!!

Add part of my code:

```
List<User> users = doListUsr(); //list of users
List<JournalArticle> listArticles = generatedListArticles(); //list of articles
for(User tmp: users){
    for(JournalArticle tmp2: listArticles){
      //check if this user has permission to view every journal article
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some more information in order to get a meaningful answer. Please state how you use this class, where it is located (deployed or external), what is Liferay version, ...

Comment: I use liferay 6.2 ce ga 5, I use this class for send a newsletter and its ubication is deployed with scheduler job , so the main idea is get the list of journal article published the last week to send this information, so... the first work is get list of journal article and get list of users for send newsletter every weekend, but I need validate if the user is autorized for see information about every journal article

Comment: It is still not clear if your class is part of Liferay module or external app. If it is Liferay plug-in you can invoke the [local services](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/finding-and-invoking-liferay-services#invoking-liferay-services-locally) otherwise you need to use [remote services](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/finding-and-invoking-liferay-services#invoking-liferay-services-remotely). The servies you are most likely interest in are [UserService](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserServ

Comment: Milen, thank you for your answer, I add part of my code, Do you have some idea which is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it with API ResourcePermission:

```
    resourcePermissionList = ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.getRoleResourcePermissions(roles[i]);
```

I get the roles of user.

Comment: Please detail how to check for a particular JournalArticle, as asked in the question. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to solve problem this way:

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)   request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
List<Role> roleList = themeDisplay.getUser().getRoles();
request.setAttribute("roleList", roleList);
```

And then use `<c:if>` tags to manage that roles in your `.jsp`

Comment: This does not check for a particular JournalArticle.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, it does! You must have userId for each JournalArticle. And you can say, for example, user with id=xxx can edit or delete this entity, and users with guest role can do nothing.